# Find the number and name of each customer that did not place an order on 10/23/2010

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having a slight issue with a question from my textbook "A Guide to SQL 8e"

the question is to "find number and name of each customer that did not place an order on October 23, 2010"

the query I wrote looks like this:

```
SELECT CustomerNum, CustomerName
FROM tblCustomer
WHERE EXISTS
(SELECT Orderdate
FROM tblOrders
Where NOT OrderDate = '10/23/2010');
```

the output is incorrect according to our answer key.

can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Without the table structures of the tables that you've used, it is not possible for us to answer your question!

Comment: You should have at least told us how the two tables are related.  Most answers below assume that the `CustomerNum` is the link, but this is not certain.

Answer (score 2):

Move `NOT` to right place:

```
SELECT CustomerNum, CustomerName
FROM tblCustomer as c
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(SELECT TOP 1 1
FROM tblOrders as o
Where c.CustomerNum = o.CustomerNum AND OrderDate = '10/23/2010');
```

Comment: You aren't linking tblOrders to tblCustomers, so it's going to return the entire tblCustomer table if there's even one tblOrders with an order date of  10/23/2010

Comment: the `top 1` is redundant, but `not exists` is how I would do it too.

Comment: @CullenMichaelThomas have you solved your problem? Can you accept this answer?

Answer (score 0):

We could also phrase this query using a join:

```
SELECT t1.CustomerNum, t1.CustomerName
FROM tblCustomer t1
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT t1.CustomerNum
    FROM tblCustomer t1
    LEFT JOIN tblOrders t2
        ON t1.CustomerNum = t2.CustomerNum
    GROUP BY t1.CustomerNum
    HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN t2.OrderDate = '10/23/2010' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
) t2
    ON t1.CustomerNum = t2.CustomerNum
WHERE t2.CustomerNum IS NULL
```

The subquery identifies all customer numbers for which one or more orders on `10/23/2010` took place.  The `WHERE` clause removes these customers.  Note that customers not having placed *any* orders would also be retained using this query.

Comment: Thank you all for the feedback and help. Failing to establish the relationship as well as moving NOT proved to be the problem. This is my first SQL class and I am still learning a lot, also first time posting here.

Answer (score 0):

Hoping i understood your question correctly.

Please check below query.

```
select CustomerNum, CustomerName from
 (
 SELECT  CustomerNum, CustomerName , 
 sum(case when Orderdate='10/23/2010' then 1 end) ord_on_23
 FROM tblOrders 
 group by CustomerNum, CustomerName
 )
 where ord_on_23=0;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would query it this way:

```
select distinct CustomerNum,CustomerName from tblCustomer
except
select o.CustomerNum,c.CustoemrName from tblCustomer c, tblOrders o where c.CustomerNumber=o.CustomerNumber and OrderDate='10/23/2010'
```